# virtual networking editor in ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vmware

I installed vmware workstation on a pc with 3 network adapters when I open virtual network editor and try to use bridge to physical I can not find the 3 network adapters all I found just eth1 and eth2 and I have renamed the 3 connections in top-right corner network Icon to other names the 3 networks appears in the top-right corner with no problems but they are missing in the virtual network editor
 Any advice ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the third adapter to the vm network.
Go to VM->Settings -> Addd -> Networking -> Select the third adapter you want to add.

If that step is already done please check wheather all the adapters are Connected and Connected on Power On.

Thanks

Comment: sorry you do not get my point here ubuntu already knows the 3 network adapters and working properly the problem is that vm virtual network editor only displays 2 of them as eth0 and eth1 the third does not in the list so I can not bridge my vm to it I need to bridge the 3 vm to the 3 physical adapters